# How to make a mutation query for inserting a list of (Array) fields in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, graphql

recently I started working on GraphQL, I am able to insert data in flat schema without any problem but when it comes to an Array of data I am getting an error like

```
 { "errors": [ {  "message": "Must be input type" } ]}
```

I am testing my query using postman, my mutation query is

```
mutation M { 

AddEvent
  (

    title: "Birthday event"   

    description:"Welcome to all" 

    media:[{url:"www.google.com", mediaType:"image" }]

    location:[{address:{state:"***", city:"****"}}]

   ) 

{title,description,media,location,created,_id}}
```

This is my Event Schema:

```
EventType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Event',
  description: 'A Event',
  fields: () => ({
   _id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The id of the event.',
    },
     id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The id of the event.',
    },
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The title of the event.',
    },
     description: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The description of the event.',
    },
    media:{
      type:new GraphQLList(mediaType),
      description:'List of media',   
    },
    location:{
      type:new GraphQLList(locationType),
      description:'List of location',   
    }  
  })
});

// Media Type

export var mediaType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Media',
  description: 'A Media',
  fields: () => ({
   _id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The id of the event.',
    },
   url:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The url of the event.',
    },
    mediaType:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The mediaTypa of the event.',
    }
  })
});

 // Location Type

export var locationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Location',
  description: 'A location',
  fields: () => ({
  _id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The id of the event.',
    },
    address:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The address.',
    },
    state:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The state.',
    },
    city:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The city.',
    },
    zip:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The zip code.',
    },
    country:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The country.',
    }
  })
});
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        match: /^([\w ,.!?]{1,100})$/
    },
    description: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        match: /^([\w ,.!?]{1,100})$/
    },
    media: [{
        url: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        mediaType: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        }
    }],
    location: [{
            address: {
                type: String
            },
            city: {
                type: String
            },
            state: {
                type: String
            },
            zip: {
                type: String
            },
            country: {
                type: String
            }
    }]
})
```

Mutation Type:

```
 addEvent: {
        type: EventType,
        args: {

        _id: {
          type: GraphQLString,
          description: 'The id of the event.',
        },
        title: {
          type: GraphQLString,
          description: 'The title of the event.',
        },
        description: {
          type: GraphQLString,
          description: 'The description of the event.',
        },
        media:{
          type:new GraphQLList(mediaType),
          description:'List of media',   
        },
        location:{
          type:new GraphQLList(locationType),
          description:'List of media',   
        },
        created: {
          type: GraphQLInt,
          description: 'The created of the user.',       
        } 
         },
      resolve: (obj, {title,description,media,location,created,_id}) => {

        let toCreateEvent = {
          title,
          description,
          created:new Date(),
          start: new Date(),
          media,
          location,
          _id,
        };

         return mongo()
            .then(db => {
              return  new Promise(
                function(resolve,reject){
              let collection = db.collection('events');
                  collection.insert(toCreateEvent, (err, result) => {
                    db.close();

                    if (err) {
                      reject(err);
                      return;
                    }
                    resolve(result);
                  });
            })
          });
       }
     }
```

Comment: I've done something similar to this (using arrays) and it works. Could you share your schema?

Comment: Hi mfirry, I added my Mongoose and GraphQL Schemas to the post. Please check them and give me reply as soon as possible.    Thank you!!

Comment: I also need the `MutationType` in which you define `AddEvent`

Comment: Please check my code i  added the mutation type. thank you...

Comment: Sorry, not enough time to work on your example. I'll link you to my little (working) sample hoping this helps you anyway. https://gist.github.com/mfirry/1ba61efcd31f7c744476

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i am not in this exact situation.I am trying to insert an array with  dictionary, not a direct array. Please check LOCATION in event Schema(mongoose Schema).

Comment: @mfirry this example works because in your `airports` mutation definition, `type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)`, `GraphQLList` and `GraphQLString` are already input types but when you create a custom type like @Mahesh you need to create it with `GraphQLInputObjectType` if you want to use it in mutations. See my answer below.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your issue is that when you define mutations, all types must be input types, hence the error you get `"Must be input type"`. So in here (from your mutation):

```
media:{
  type:new GraphQLList(mediaType),
  description:'List of media',   
},
location:{
  type:new GraphQLList(locationType),
  description:'List of media',   
},
```

`GraphQLList`, `mediaType` and `locationType` must be input types.

`GraphQLList` is already an input type (see here https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/definition.js#L74-L82 to see the list of GraphQL types considered as input types).

However your types `mediaType` and `locationType` are of `GraphQLObjectType` type, which is not an input type but if you look at the list of input types again: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/definition.js#L74-L82, you'll find `GraphQLInputObjectType` which is an object input type, so, what you need to do is to replace `mediaType` and `locationType` by their "input" version.

What I suggest to do is to create `mediaInputType` and `locationInputType` which would have the same field structure as `mediaType` and `locationType` but created with `new GraphQLInputObjectType({...` instead of `new GraphQLObjectType({...` and use them in your mutation.

I ran into the same issue and I solved it like that, feel free to comment if you have any question.

Comment: This is awesome but it doesn't seem to work for me.. What am I doing wrong? Heres my mutationType
https://gist.github.com/piq9117/64cee784677915edc1da8ffec7ffa383

Comment: Hi @adriantoine, can you provide the code of the mutation with usage of input.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem - I did not know how to specify array of objects in the input definition. So for those who wants to see a "text" schema solution:

```
type Book {
  title: String!
}
```

to have an array of Books in your input type

```
input AuthorInput {
  name: String!
  age: Int!
}
```

you can not just add `books: [Book!]` inside the input statement, you will need deliberately create input type containing needed fields (duplicate if you like):

```
input BookInput {
  title: String!
}
```

and then you can:

```
input AuthorInput {
  name: String!
  age: Int!
  books: [BookInput!]
}
```