# I need to push array data to mongodb using graphql

Tags: graphql, mongoose-schema

My data is

```
Array[3]
  0: Object
    time: "0:00",
    value: 4
  1: Object
    time: "0:00",
    value: 7
  2: Object
    time: "0:02"
    value: -6
```

I need to push this array of data to mongodb using graphql with **mutation**..please give me some ideas or sample code to finish. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How to make a mutation query for inserting a list of (Array) fields in GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304486/how-to-make-a-mutation-query-for-inserting-a-list-of-array-fields-in-graphql). This question does a good job of showing an example of a mutation using Node.js

Comment: Tried this one doesn't working... my current schema                          `var mongoose = require('mongoose') ; 
 var dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema([{

  _id : Number
  value: Number,
  time: String,
  

}]); 

 var data = mongoose.model('datas', dataSchema);
 exports.default = data;`

Comment: My question is having the input array format as [ [{obj1}] [{obj2}] [{obj3}] ] . I need to push this array into mongodb using graphql give some suggestions for developing mongoose schema and graphql schema.

Comment: Is the problem you are having getting the data from the resolve method in graphQL or saving it into your moongoose schema?